# Issues with my c# loop

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop

I am making like a cash register system which collects the number of items you put in, then it will ask you to input the price of each item (depends on how many items you entered).

I have a loop which should take the numbers from the array and add them to the total variable, well I think, please help!

**CODE:**

```
private void runtotal()
{
    for(int i = 0; i > numbers.Length; i++)
    {
        total = total + numbers[i];
    }
}
```

numbers = the array which the prices are stored in
total = the prices added together should be in here.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Misprint. Should be `i < numbers.Length;`.

Comment: @Aleks look up how to use `for loops, foreach loops, while loops, and do while loops` understand the differences also use some of `Linq's` Extension methods like `.Sum()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This

```
 for(int i = 0; i > numbers.Length; i++)
```

should change to this

```
 for(int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
```

The `numbers` is an array and it has a `Length` property, which is the number of items that are stored in the array. The first item is stored in the position 0 and the last in the position `numbers.Length-1`. So this condition, `i > numbers.Length` doesn't make sense.

Furthermore, you have to think about what is a `for` statetemt.

If you want to repeat an action multiple time, you can use a `for` statement.

Usually, `for` statement has a looping variable, which is used to monitor the loops. It starts one some value and ends at another value (usually). In addition to this, a condition is checked in each step. If this is true the step would be executed, otherwise we have hit the end of the `for` statetement. By the way the are loops that never ends, for instance `for(;;)`, but this is not of your concern at this case.

In this case the variable is `i`. The starting value is 0 and the condition you check in each step was this `i > numbers.Length`. Obviously, this condition is `false` and none step would be executed.

For a complete reference, regarding the `for` statement, please have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx).

As a side note a few comments about your method. Supposing that `numbers` is an array of `int` I would suggest you refactor your method like below:

```
private int Sum(int[] numbers)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + numbers[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Compare this method with the initial.

- It has a more clear name that the initial method (starting with a capital letter, as is the usual convention).
- You pass as an argument an array of integers. (So you have a specific input and you expect a specific output, the sum of these integers)
- The sum is a local variable to this method. There isn't any reason for a counter like this, to be class level field.
- This method now can be used anywhere you want for calculating the sum of the integers that are stored in an array of integers and not an array that is a filed to a specific class. Surely to do so, you have to place it in another class and make it public. However, I think that you got the point. (However, you have to keep an eye if the sum gets too big, [integer overflows](http://projects.webappsec.org/w/page/13246946/Integer%20Overflows). But that's the general idea).

Comment: I would note that the use of `for` in this case is pretty much inviting mistakes for this use case, and he should opt for `foreach` (or a declarative solution like LINQ's `.Sum()`...

Comment: @willaien good point, but in this case the OP should understand why his code is not correct. Certainly, I would opt on using the LINQ `Sum` method, but I strongly believe that we have to learn the basics first and the go on abstractions like this. It's personal view, not necessarily the best :)

Comment: fair enough. I wouldn't tell a fairly new person to use LINQ right off the bat, and understanding why his code doesn't work is certainly valuable, since he seems to be struggling with it, but, in general, I tell people to avoid for loops unless needed (but certainly understand it, because it's sometimes necessary)

Comment: It fixed it to make the actual number output, but if I input 3 items into my system and I label each of them for the price of $5, it apparently makes the sum 10 when it should be 15.

Comment: @Aleks This can't be true. You argue that if `numbers` is an array with three items, which all of them have the same value (5), then the Sum method returns 10?

Comment: @Christos Ok, the loop works perfectly fine but I just have an issue with adding the items which I can solve my self, thanks for the previous comment above!

Comment: @You are welcome dude. I am glad that I helped :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the condition in the `for` loop **has to be valid** in order to do another loop. Since your condition is:

```
i > numbers.Length
```

and `i` is initialized with `0` and a length is greater than or equal to `0`. The **condition will be `false` for the first run** and thus the `for` loop will never run.

You can solve it by using another condition:

```
i < numbers.Length
```

## Foreach

Since one loops regularly over arrays, lists, etc. C# (and many other programming languages) have a concept called a `foreach` loop: if the datastructure impelements the `IEnumerable<T>` interface (which an array does), you can use the `foreach` like:

```
foreach(int number in numbers) {
    total += number;
}
```

This is safer and shows more what you are doing: for each `number` in `numbers` you will add the number to `total`.

## Declarative approach

Nevertheless it is beter to use a more declarative approach. You can use LINQs [`Sum`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338442%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) extension method:

```
using System.Linq;

//...

private void runtotal() {
    total = numbers.Sum();
    //do something with total
}
```

without using any `for` loop. Using a builtin is in general better because it tends to let your code show *what you want to calculate* and less *how you do that*, furthermore these builtins are less likely to *contain bugs* and finally in some cases they are *very optimized* and thus will outperform a naive approach.

Comment: It fixed it to make the actual number output, but if I input 3 items into my system and I label each of them for the price of $5, it apparently makes the sum 10 when it should be 15.